# Are the Galois actions on automorphisms of twists isomorphic?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, group-cohomology, galois-descent

This might be a trivial question and I might be overlooking something:

Suppose $k$ is a field with algebraic closure $\overline k$ and absolute Galois group $\Gamma$. Let $X,Y$ be two distinct varieties over $k$ that are isomorphic over $\overline k$. Consider their automorphisms groups $Aut_{\overline k}(X)$ and $Aut_{\overline k}(Y)$. These groups are isomorphic as abstract groups but they each also have a Galois action of $\Gamma$ acting on the groups by conjugation.

Are these two automorphism groups isomorphic as "groups with a $\Gamma$ action"? Note that $H^1(\Gamma,Aut_{\overline k}(X)) \cong H^1(\Gamma,Aut_{\overline k}(X))$ because both groups classify twists of $X$ (or equivalently of $Y$).

If these two "groups with $\Gamma$ action" are distinct, are their higher cohomologies distinct too in any examples? How are these two related otherwise?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are not. $H^0(\Gamma, \text{Aut}(X_{\bar{k}}))$ computes the subgroup of automorphisms which are Galois-invariant, which is equivalently the automorphism group of $X$, and similarly for $Y$, so to find a counterexample it suffices to find varieties $X, Y$ which are isomorphic over $\bar{k}$ but which have non-isomorphic automorphism groups over $k$.

Let $k = \mathbb{R}$, let $X = \mathbb{P}^1$, and let $Y$ be the conic $\{ X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 = 0 \}$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$. Then $\text{Aut}(X) \cong PGL_2(\mathbb{R})$ but $\text{Aut}(Y) \cong PO(3) \cong SO(3)$ (actually I'm not entirely confident I know how to prove this, at least not without passing to the complexification). These two groups can be distinguished abstractly by their abelianizations: I believe (but haven't checked carefully) that the abelianization of $PGL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is $\{ \pm 1 \}$ (given by the sign of the determinant) but the abelianization of $SO(3)$ is trivial.

Comment: You can see (at least intuitively) that twisting can kill (or introduce) automorphisms over the base field: by twisting the Fermat cubic $x^3+y^3+z^3=0$ you obtain e.g. $ax^3+by^3+cz^3=0$, where all of the symmetry is broken.

Comment: I think you can even get a hands-on $0$-dimensional counterexample: Let $X = \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2 + 1)x$ and $Y=\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2-1)x$. Then I'd think that over $\mathbb{C}$ both have automorphism group $\Sigma_3$, but the action is trivial for $Y$ and conjugation with a transposition for $X$. (Am I messing anything up here?)

Comment: @AchimKrause I think that is correct. Another way to see it is to write out the automorphisms of $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$ in terms of their corresponding ring isomorphisms: they are given by $x \mapsto x$, $x \mapsto -x$, $x \mapsto (2x+i)(x-i)$, $x \mapsto (2x-i)(x+i)$, $x \mapsto (-2x-i)(x-i)$, and $x \mapsto (2x+i)(x+i)$ if I haven't made any mistakes. Now it is easy to see that only the first two are stable under complex conjugation. For me, the Galois action is always easier to understand on the ring level, since the action there is just given by the action on the coefficients.

Comment: That's great, thanks! I thought of the twisted $\mathbb P^1$ example too but I too did not know how to compute the automorphism group of the conic over the reals. It's a little strange to me to be having two different groups with $\Gamma$ actions that nevertheless give the same $H^1$. Is there a purely group theoretic explanation of what's going on here? For instance, is there some classification of what sort of different $\Gamma$ actions can you get by twisting?

Comment: @Asvin: when you stipulate that $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic over $\bar{k}$ you're imposing exactly that they have the same forms but that's all you're imposing. If you work through the proof that $H^1$ classifies forms what you'll see is that different $1$-cocycles are used to twist the Galois action (starting from a base; in other words the bijection requires picking a $k$-form) and taking fixed points of that action is what produces the different forms.

Comment: Right, I understand from the twist point of view why the forms are isomorphic (and one can define an explicit isomorphism on $H^1$) but I was wondering if this was the reflection of some more general construction in group cohomology.

Comment: @Asvin: you may be interested in reading a sequence of blog posts I wrote about how to describe Galois descent in terms of homotopy fixed points. The punchline is here but you may have to go back a few posts for context: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/11/17/forms-and-galois-cohomology/